# How to match coefficients of a SVF compared to Biquad in order to Plot the frequency response?

Tags: filters, frequency-response, biquad

I'd like to output the frequency response of [this](https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_dsp/processors/juce_StateVariableTPTFilter.cpp) filter.

[Here's](https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/master/modules/juce_dsp/processors/juce_StateVariableTPTFilter.cpp#L125C1-L130C2) how the coefficients are calculated:

```
void StateVariableTPTFilter<SampleType>::update()
{
    g  = static_cast<SampleType> (std::tan (juce::MathConstants<double>::pi * cutoffFrequency / sampleRate));
    R2 = static_cast<SampleType> (1.0 / resonance);
    h  = static_cast<SampleType> (1.0 / (1.0 + R2 * g + g * g));
}
```

The method that I actually use to plot the freq response (of a biquad filter) is the one suggested by earlevel on one of [his](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2016/12/01/evaluating-filter-frequency-response/) topic. Code I wrote is:

```
// zeros
std::complex<double> resZeros(0.0, 0.0);
resZeros += mCoefficients.mA0 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -0 * freq * k2PI));
resZeros += mCoefficients.mA1 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -1 * freq * k2PI));
resZeros += mCoefficients.mA2 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -2 * freq * k2PI));

// poles
std::complex<double> resPoles(0.0, 0.0);
resPoles += 1.0 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -0 * freq * k2PI));
resPoles += mCoefficients.mB1 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -1 * freq * k2PI));
resPoles += mCoefficients.mB2 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -2 * freq * k2PI));

std::complex<double> res = resZeros / resPoles;

// magnitude
float magnitude = (float)std::abs(res);
if (std::isnan(magnitude)) {
    magnitude = 0.0f;
}

// phase
float phase = (float)std::arg(res); // i.e. math.atan2(res.im, res.re)
if (std::isnan(phase)) {
    phase = 0.0f;
}

return std::polar(magnitude, phase);
```

Basically, now I need to match the g, R2 and h coefficients from the SVF filter to the ones earlevel provide as mA0, mA1, mA2, mB1 and mB2.

Tried some test, but it doesn't works at all, such as:

```
mCoefficients.mA0 = mG;
mCoefficients.mA1 = mR2;
mCoefficients.mA2 = mH;
```

Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you're asking but the frequency (and phase) response of that SVF is identical to a biquad filter whose coefficients were calculated using the bilinear Z-transform.